# Java 8 update 121 missing JavaFX Dialog and Alert classes?

Tags: javafx, dialog, alert

I'm developing a JavaFX application and can't seem to import the Alert and Dialog classes that were released with Java 8 update 40 (Java 1.8.0_40).  My version of Java is the newest version (1.8.0_121-b13).  Did they remove Alert and Dialog from the latest version?  How do I even find what classes are included in a specific Java release?

Here is my attempt to import:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
```

It is okay up to the package `control` but cannot find the class `Dialog`.

**Other information**
Using Netbeans as my IDE

Project Properties:

> Sources >> Source/Binary Format: JDK8
>
> Sources >> Profile: Full JRE
>
> Libraries >> Java Platform: JDK 1.8 (Default)

Comment: No, they are still there. You probably have something configured incorrectly in your IDE (pointing to an old version, perhaps).

Comment: I did check that... using Netbeans by the way.  I went into Project Properties and under Sources it says using JDK 8, Full JRE; under Libraries, Java Platform says JDK 1.8...  are there other places to configure that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't use NetBeans, but you need to make sure it is specifically pointing to the correct update (i.e. jdk 1.8.0_121, not jdk 1.8.0_xxx for xxx < 40). You can easily enough find the jfxrt.jar file (in `jre/lib/ext`) and do `tar tf jfxrt.jar | grep Alert` to convince yourself that the `Alert` class is there.

Comment: @James_D Thanks so much for the tip... I did find a rt.jar in my "..\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib" folder and that has a lot of the familiar java classes  but I could not find a jfxrt.jar file anywhere.  Is there a different place where it is stored?

Comment: In `ext`, under `lib`. What OS are you using? This is Oracle JDK, right?

Comment: @James_D, Yes, you are correct... the file is in the ext folder and when I browser the contents I do find the Alert class.  So now it's just figuring out why my IDE doesn't make it accessible.  I am using Windows 10 and it is the official Oracle Java.

Comment: I have the same problem here, I found the jfxrt.jar file, and inside there are not any Dialog or Alert classes

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to James_D for helping me determine that I did actually have the classes on my hard disk (see the comments section of the original question).  I then knew it was just a matter of configuring Netbeans properly.  (Programming is not my main job so spending time trying to learn what all the settings & menus mean in the IDE is quite overwhelming right now, though I am learning bit by bit).

Anyway, I found what I needed under the menu:

> Tools >> Java Platforms

Even though I have the latest JDK installed, this was still pointing to jdk1.8.0_20 which is pre-JavaFX Alert & Dialog classes.

Adding a new Java Platform and then going into Project Properties and setting it there fixed my issue.